# How to make player rotate smoothly

Tags: godot

Below is my entire player script (sorry if it is messy) and it would be really helpful if you could tell me why the rotation isn't working. I want the player to turn smoothly when the player presses a key. Thanks so much!

```
extends KinematicBody

var moveSpeed : float = 5.0
var jumpForce : float = 10.0
var gravity : float = 20
var vel : Vector3 = Vector3()
const _angular_speed:float = TAU
    
func _physics_process(delta):
    vel.x = 0
    vel.z = 0
    
    var turn_input := Vector2(
            Input.get_action_strength("move_left") - Input.get_action_strength("move_right"),
            Input.get_action_strength("move_forward") - Input.get_action_strength("move_backward")
    )
    var movement = Vector3()
    var input_angle := turn_input.angle()
    var _target_angle:float
    var angle_diff := wrapf(_target_angle - rotation.y, -PI, PI)
    rotation.y += clamp(delta * _angular_speed, 0, abs(angle_diff)) * sign(angle_diff)
        
    if Input.is_action_pressed("move_forward") and Input.is_action_pressed("move_left"):
        movement[2] = 1
        movement[0] = 1
    elif Input.is_action_pressed("move_forward") and Input.is_action_pressed("move_right"):
        movement[2] = 1
        movement[0] = -1
    elif Input.is_action_pressed("move_backward") and Input.is_action_pressed("move_left"):
        movement[2] = -1
        movement[0] = 1
    elif Input.is_action_pressed("move_backward") and Input.is_action_pressed("move_right"):
        movement[2] = -1
        movement[0] = -1
    else:
        if Input.is_action_pressed("move_forward"):
            movement[2] = 1
        if Input.is_action_pressed("move_backward"):
            movement[2] = -1
        if Input.is_action_pressed("move_left"):
            movement[0] = 1
        if Input.is_action_pressed("move_right"):
            movement[0] = -1
        
    movement = movement.normalized()
    global_transform[3] += movement/7
    
    vel.y -= gravity * delta
    
    if Input.is_action_pressed("jump") and is_on_floor():
        vel.y = jumpForce
    
    vel = move_and_slide(vel, Vector3.UP)
```

Edit: This question has now been answered.

Comment: Why are you starting a new thread for an existing question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69823647/how-do-i-rotate-smoothly-in-godot

Comment: It was the easiest way for me to reply to the comments from the previous post

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It wasn’t me (though I should have). It is because you are spamming the forum with multiple topics relating to a single question.

Comment: Ok thanks that it wasn't you Dúthomhas. The reason I did this is it was the only way I knew I could reply to Theraot as it was too long for a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing some odd mix of things here.

---

**Unused `input_angle`**

First, of all, just copying the over to Godot. I get a warning that `input_angle` is not used. And after a quick look, `_target_angle` right next is never assigned:

```
var input_angle := turn_input.angle()
var _target_angle:float
```

That is an easy fix. Just keep `_target_angle`:

```
var _target_angle := turn_input.angle()
```

---

**Clean up**

Second, not really a problem, but `movement` is this:

```
var movement := Vector3(turn_input.x, 0.0, turn_input.y).normalized()
```

With that, you see all this code:

```
    if Input.is_action_pressed("move_forward") and Input.is_action_pressed("move_left"):
        movement[2] = 1
        movement[0] = 1
    elif Input.is_action_pressed("move_forward") and Input.is_action_pressed("move_right"):
        movement[2] = 1
        movement[0] = -1
    elif Input.is_action_pressed("move_backward") and Input.is_action_pressed("move_left"):
        movement[2] = -1
        movement[0] = 1
    elif Input.is_action_pressed("move_backward") and Input.is_action_pressed("move_right"):
        movement[2] = -1
        movement[0] = -1
    else:
        if Input.is_action_pressed("move_forward"):
            movement[2] = 1
        if Input.is_action_pressed("move_backward"):
            movement[2] = -1
        if Input.is_action_pressed("move_left"):
            movement[0] = 1
        if Input.is_action_pressed("move_right"):
            movement[0] = -1
        
    movement = movement.normalized()
```

Delete it. Gone. Just keep the one liner above. It should do the same thing. *It should do the same thing, with the weird behavior and all, but it is easier to see the code now.*

---

The code looks like this now:

```
extends KinematicBody

var moveSpeed : float = 5.0
var jumpForce : float = 10.0
var gravity : float = 20
var vel : Vector3 = Vector3()
const _angular_speed:float = TAU
    
func _physics_process(delta):
    vel.x = 0
    vel.z = 0
    var turn_input := Vector2(
        Input.get_action_strength("move_left") - Input.get_action_strength("move_right"),
        Input.get_action_strength("move_forward") - Input.get_action_strength("move_backward")
    )
    var _target_angle := turn_input.angle()
    var angle_diff := wrapf(_target_angle - rotation.y, -PI, PI)
    rotation.y += clamp(delta * _angular_speed, 0, abs(angle_diff)) * sign(angle_diff)
    var movement := Vector3(turn_input.x, 0.0, turn_input.y).normalized()
    global_transform[3] += movement/7
    vel.y -= gravity * delta
    if Input.is_action_pressed("jump") and is_on_floor():
        vel.y = jumpForce
    
    vel = move_and_slide(vel, Vector3.UP)
```

---

**What the `movement`?**

Look at this line:

```
global_transform[3] += movement/7
```

*What the Hell, Michigan?*

That line is equivalent to this:

```
global_transform.origin += movement * 1/7
```

Notice this is motion, and it is not using `delta`. I will come back to that.

---

**Rotation resetting**

We need to promote `_target_angle` to a field, and only set it when there is some input. *I also did clean the field further.* The code now looks like this:

```
extends KinematicBody

const _angular_speed:float = TAU

var moveSpeed := 5.0
var jumpForce := 10.0
var gravity := 20
var vel := Vector3()

var _target_angle:float
    
func _physics_process(delta):
    vel.x = 0
    vel.z = 0
    var turn_input := Vector2(
        Input.get_action_strength("move_left") - Input.get_action_strength("move_right"),
        Input.get_action_strength("move_forward") - Input.get_action_strength("move_backward")
    )
    if turn_input.length_squared() > 0:
        _target_angle = turn_input.angle()

    var angle_diff := wrapf(_target_angle - rotation.y, -PI, PI)
    rotation.y += clamp(delta * _angular_speed, 0, abs(angle_diff)) * sign(angle_diff)
    var movement := Vector3(turn_input.x, 0.0, turn_input.y).normalized()
    global_transform[3] += movement/7
    vel.y -= gravity * delta
    if Input.is_action_pressed("jump") and is_on_floor():
        vel.y = jumpForce
    
    vel = move_and_slide(vel, Vector3.UP)
```

As you can see I declare `target_angle` at the start, so it is not a local variable. That way, it keeps its value. Also I do this:

```
if turn_input.length_squared() > 0:
    _target_angle = turn_input.angle()
```

That way, only when `turn_input` is not empty, it sets `_target_angle`.

---

**Wrong direction**

It seems to be moving in the opposite direction it should. I'm not sure if this is intentional or not, given that I kept the order you had.

Anyway, fixing it is a matter of flipping the input:

```
    var turn_input := Vector2(
        Input.get_action_strength("move_right") - Input.get_action_strength("move_left"),
        Input.get_action_strength("move_backward") - Input.get_action_strength("move_forward")
    )
```

This makes sense given that `x` grows to the right, and - actually - forward in Godot is negative `z` (here stored in the `y`).

---

**Wrong orientation**

The rotation of the character seems to be off by a quarter turn. This solves it:

```
_target_angle = 0.75 * TAU - turn_input.angle()
```

*Actually it makes sense given that `turn_input.angle()` would be measured from the `x` axis, but 0 rotation is looking down the `z` axis. I did overlook that.*

---

**Motion again**

Instead of changing the `origin` of the transform (by snaky means, no less), use `move_and_slide`, which you are already using. Thus, we are not going to have `movement`, instead we are going to write to `vel`. To ease doing that, I decided to normalize `turn_input` so we can use it directly to compute `vel`. And while we are at it, let us use the `moveSpeed` field you have. *Which is very small by the way.*

This is the final code:

```
extends KinematicBody

const _angular_speed:float = TAU

var moveSpeed := 500.0
var jumpForce := 10.0
var gravity := 20
var vel := Vector3()

var _target_angle:float
    
func _physics_process(delta:float) -> void:
    # Input
    var turn_input := Vector2(
        Input.get_action_strength("move_right") - Input.get_action_strength("move_left"),
        Input.get_action_strength("move_backward") - Input.get_action_strength("move_forward")
    ).normalized()
    
    # Rotation
    if turn_input.length_squared() > 0:
        _target_angle = 0.75 * TAU - turn_input.angle()

    var angle_diff := wrapf(_target_angle - rotation.y, -PI, PI)
    rotation.y += clamp(delta * _angular_speed, 0, abs(angle_diff)) * sign(angle_diff)
    
    # Velocity
    vel.x = turn_input.x * moveSpeed * delta
    vel.z = turn_input.y * moveSpeed * delta
    vel.y -= gravity * delta
    if Input.is_action_pressed("jump") and is_on_floor():
        vel.y = jumpForce

    # Motion
    vel = move_and_slide(vel, Vector3.UP)
```

Comment: Wow Theraot, I can't thank you enough. The code is working well and what you explained   made a lot of sense. Thanks Again!