# How to get the property name from key?

Tags: godot, gdscript

I'm trying to get a list of all the properties and the values that are being changed from an animation player node,
but how do I get the property name of node that the animation key is changing?

maybe something like this:

```
var ani=aniplayer.get_animation('running');
    
for i in range(0,ani.get_track_count()):
        var key_idx=ani.track_find_key(i,0,0);
        print("property=>",ani.get_key_property(i,key_idx)," new value=>",ani.track_get_key_value(i,key_idx));
```

Answer (score 0):

Let us say you have an animation player:

```
var aniplayer := $AnimationPlayer as AnimationPlayer
```

And you get an animation by name:

```
var ani := aniplayer.get_animation("running")
```

As you know you can get the number of tracks the animations has:

```
var track_count := ani.get_track_count()
```

And, of course we can loop:

```
for track_id in range(0,track_count):
    pass
```

---

Let us see, you want to know what property is being set. To get the property, we need to get the path, and extract the property from there:

```
for track_id in range(0,track_count):
    var track_path := (ani.track_get_path(track_id) as String).split(":")
    var node_path := track_path[0]
    var property_path := track_path[1]
```

---

**Addendum**:

There is another way to get the property path from a `NodePath`: [`get_concatenated_subnames`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_nodepath.html?highlight=NodePath#class-nodepath-method-get-concatenated-subnames).

Or we can get the elements separated with [`get_subname`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_nodepath.html?highlight=NodePath#class-nodepath-method-get-subname).

So this is the property name:

```
var property_path = ani.track_get_path(track_id).get_subname(0)
```

I guess this is good time as any to bring attention to the fact that `AnimationPlayer` can animate sub-properties. With `get_subname(0)` you get the property, but not the sub-property.

For example, you don't have to animate `position`, you can animate `position.y` and you would do that by adding `:y` at the end of the track name in the Animation panel. *I describe how to do it with more detail [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69623533/402022).* In this case `get_subname(0)` will give you `position`, but `get_concatenated_subnames()` will give you `position:y`.

Comment: I was afraid you might use `split()` , I thought there might be an inbuilt method that I was missing

Comment: @cakelover Guess what? There is: [`get_concatenated_subnames`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_nodepath.html?highlight=NodePath#class-nodepath-method-get-concatenated-subnames) - It had not occurred to me to check.

Comment: any idea which is more efficient? `split()` or `get_concatenated_subnames`?

Comment: @cakelover After having a look at the source code I can tell that using `get_subname` or `get_concatenated_subnames` according to your needs is faster than converting to `String` and manipulating it. The reason being that the `NodePath` is not an string internally, but an array of strings. So using `split` results in concatenating the components just to split them again, which is wasted effort.

Comment: also how do I get the node path without the sub-name? or will I have to convert to string for that?

Comment: @cakelover I believe converting to string is the better way to get a `NodePath` only for the node, as I don't see the equivalent of `get_concatenated_subnames` but for the node. However, you might not need to. If you have a `NodePath` that includes subnames (i.e. it has a property path) and you pass it to `get_node`, you still get the node and the subnames are ignored. Edit: that reminds me, the paths of the tracks are relative to the `root_node` of the `AnimationPlayer` (and you could also change `root_node` for quick and dirty animation re-target).