# How do I make sure that all changes are not discarded after the animation? Godot

Tags: godot

After playing the animation several times, the object resets all movements and rotations(3d mode) each time and remains in one place. How do I make sure that all changes are not discarded after the animation?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changes are not discarded after the animation. Period.

However, changes are reset when the animation starts again.

If you don't want the animation to change a property, don't include it in the animation. *Or, put another way, if you don't want to reset a property, don't play an animation that includes it.*

---

If you want the motion of the animation to be relative, you can animate a child node. For instance, you can have a physics body player character (e.g. `RigidBody` or `KinematicBody`), and then as a child have the model that represents it… And animate with `AnimationPlayer` the model, no the physics body. That way, the animation will reset the model to its parent (the physics body), but will not reset the physics body itself.

---

If you need finer granularity over what you track, consider using sub-properties. I have an explanation in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69623533/402022). It could be that animation is not the right tool for what you are doing. Consider using `Tween`, for example.

*By the way, if you want to smoothly interpolate between animation, you can increase the animation blend time (which is 0 by default). I talk about that in yet a [different answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67516886/402022).*